# Mongo DB Join on Primary/Foreign Key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, join, left-join

I have two collections, viz: `clib` and `mp`.
The schema for `clib` is : `{name: String, type: Number}` and that for `mp` is: `{clibId: String}`.

Sample Document for `clib`:

```
{_id: ObjectId("6178008397be0747443a2a92"), name: "c1", type: 1}
{_id: ObjectId("6178008397be0747443a2a91"), name: "c2", type: 0}
```

Sample Document for `mp`:

```
{clibId: "6178008397be0747443a2a92"}
{clibId:"6178008397be0747443a2a91"}
```

While Querying `mp`, I want those `clibId's` that have `type = 0` in `clib` collection.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

One approach that I can think of was to use `$lookUp`, but that doesnt seem to be working. Also, I m not sure if this is anti-pattern for mongodb, another approach is to copy the `type` from `clib` to `mp` while saving `mp document`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.mp.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "clib",
      let: {
        clibId: "$clibId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [ "$_id", "$$clibId" ],
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: { type: 1, _id: 0 }
        }
      ],
      as: "clib"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$clib"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "clib.type": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VneKYiBWqeI)

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly you can use a pipeline like this:

This query get the values from `clib` where its `_id` is the same as `clibId` and also has `type = 0`. Also I've added a `$match` stage to not output values where there is not any coincidence.

```
db.mp.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "clib",
      "let": {
        "id": "$clibId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    {
                      "$toObjectId": "$$id"
                    },
                    "$_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$type",
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "result": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_PXF0AQlonr)

Comment: Your welcome. Also for efficiency is better avoid $unwind if you can